# Defining Classes that Contain Pointers to Each Other

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I have a series of classes in C++ that contain pointers to each other for interconnection reasons. The code is as follows:

```
class Cell;

//classes
class Connection {
public:
    Cell * source;

    virtual bool trigger() {
        return source->trigger();  //line 16, source of the error
    }

    //constructors
    //default
    Connection() {
        source = NULL;
    }

    //call
    Connection(Cell * in) {
        source = in;
    }

    //copy
    Connection(const Connection & in) {
        source = in.source;
    }
};

class NotConnection : Connection {
public:
    virtual bool trigger() override {
        return !source->trigger();
    }

    //constructors
    //default
    NotConnection() {
        source = NULL;
    }

    //call
    NotConnection(Cell * in) {
        source = in;
    }

    //copy
    NotConnection(const NotConnection & in) {
        source = in.source;
    }
};


class Cell {
public:
    vector<Connection *> parents;

    virtual bool trigger() = 0;

    ~Cell() {
        for (int i = 0; i < parents.size(); i++) {
            delete parents[i];
        }
    }
};
```

I thought I could use forward declaration to clear up any compilation issues but when I attempt to build the project I get the error:

```
source.cpp(16): error C2027: use of undefined type 'Cell'
```

I tried re-ordering the classes and forward declaring `Connection` instead and that did not work either, my question is why is the compiler throwing this error and what can I do to resolve it?

Comment: Um... which line is line 16?

Comment: I added a comment to show which line is 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access a member of a class that has not been defined yet, because the compiler doesn't yet know the class's set of members.

You must declare `trigger` first and then define it after the definition of `Cell` has been seen.

```
class Cell;

class Connection {
public:
    Cell * source;    
    virtual bool trigger();
};

class Cell {
    // definition of Cell
};

inline bool Connection::trigger() {
    return source->trigger();
}
```

Comment: Is it considered good etiquette to define all classes as prototypes first and then write the implementations afterward so as to avoid this error in the future?

Answer (score 0):

You can use forward-declared classes when declaring pointers or references to them, but you cannot actually use those types.

Move your `connection::trigger()` implementation to a `.cpp` file, or define it as `inline` after the definition of the `cell` class.